# Find number that follows certain string which includes both letters and punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

I am trying to find a way to extract the numbers that occur after `abc/` immediately succeeding the `/` and before any further letters, numbers or punctuation.

E.g:

`abc/134567/something` should return **1234567**

`abc/1234567?foo=bar` should still only return **1234567**

`blah/1234/abc/678` should only return **678** as I'm looking only for the number that succeeds `abc/`

I'm aware there are two options: regex or substring match.

In order to perform the substring match I need the index point but I'm dubious about merely doing an `indexOf("abc/")` as it only returns the index of the first letter - a - which could be present elsewhere in the string.

With regex I have struggled as I find that searching for a mixture of the letters and the slashes seems to cause it to return null.

So what's the best way?

Comment: You should read a bit about [regex](https://regexone.com/), it's not hard(https://regex101.com/r/cplaPU/1)

Comment: what are you looking for, the substring as number, or the index of the starting pattern?

Comment: I really thing that the only thing you where missing is escaping the `/` with a `\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regexpression :

```
var rgx = new RegExp("abc\/([0-9]+)","gi");
```

Then :

```
var m = rgx.exec("abc/1234567?foo=bar");
console.log(m[0]);
```

**edited after comments**

Comment: This returns the string with the `abc/` prepending - I only require the number after

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and seach for `abc/` and following digits.

```js
var array = ['abc/134567/something', 'abc/1234567?foo=bar', 'blah/1234/abc/678'];

console.log(array.map(s => s.match(/abc\/(\d+)/)[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

We accept string that has `abc/`, after it an integer number, **that is taken as a matched group** and either the end of string or some non-digit symbol after it.

```
abc\/(\d+)(?:$|\D)
```

[test](https://regex101.com/r/F2vfXO/1)

You'll use in Javascript for matched group extraction:

```
var myRegexp = /abc\/(\d+)(?:$|\D)/g; 
var match = myRegexp.exec(inputString);
var result=match[1]; // the number after abc/
```

In another regex engine than that of JavaScript, lookahead and lookbehind could be used. But in JS lookbehinds are forbidden. :-(. So we have to use this, a bit more complicated, way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this:

```
^(.*\/)(\d+)(.*)
```

Where the second group will give you the digits after the slash.

[Look at the regex here](https://regex101.com/r/dgI0Wa/1)